# Column validation with multiple arguments

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, validation

I have two columns that wish to validate on. Column A is a number field and Column B is a choice (drop-down) field. I wish to restrict the options that can be selected in Column B if the number entered in Column A is less than 8. Is this possible please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This can be done something like below

```
=IF([ColumnA]<8, IF([ColumnB]='Option1', true, false), true)
```

If columnA value is less than 8 it check 
    if columnB value is option1 then return true
    else return false
else
    return true

Similarly you can nest all the other option values that need to be validated

Comment: That worked perfectly - a problem I have been unable to solve for the last 2 hours has now gone away. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!

Comment: Mark his answer as correct if it worked for you

Comment: Yes sir, sir. Or is it boss?